# Matching two data sets with C# and LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, merge, datatable, ienumerable

I have to import information from a plain text file, matching it to a DB Record using three fields.

```
DB fields
RowId, DF1, DF2, DF3, 

Text file fields
TF1,TF2,TF3,TF4

Matching
DF1 = TF1
DF2 = TF2
DF3 = TF3

Result
RowID, TF4 (Optional, F1,F2,F3)
```

Due to my limited experience with C# and LinQ, this is proving troublesome.

I tried loading the DB table and the text file into a DataTable each, and converting them asEnumerable() for use with LinQ, but cannot find a code reference to construct the LinQ
properly.

```
var result = (from db in dtDB.AsEnumerable()
join txt in dtTxt.AsEnumerable() on <<MATCH INSTRUCTION>>
where << WHERE INSTRUCTION >>
select new {
           db.RowID,
//         F1,
//         F2,
//         F3,
           txt.TF4
}).asArray
```

The problem is how to reference each field in the "Enumerable" and construct the Match and Where instructions.
Should I use other structure instead of DataTables?
Any pointers on how to solve this would be helpful.

Comment: Is `DF3 = TF2` a typo?

Comment: Few too many unknowns here for me; where should the data end up? On screen? In db? In another file? What does the text file actually look like? What does the existing data access to the database table look like? Why pick datatables (they're awkward to linq, or even, just awkward in general)? Why LINQ? What do you hope it offers you?

Comment: Caius, yes, it was a typo, fixed it. About the rest, I use what I know of C#, that is DataTables, I haven't used anything else yet. This is for a stand alone library that must be used both as backend for an AngularJs front and a C# program. The Db is SQL server, but that can change any minute now, so it has to be abstracted by linq. The file is a positional text file, that is read in another method that returns whatever I need (a DataTable so far, can be changed).

Comment: "Abstracted by LINQ" in relation to a database usually actually means Entity Framework.. am I right in thinking that you have this set up/are setting it up? DataTaes are great for a lot of things, but long in the tooth now. If this was new dev I'd probably look at eg CsvHelper for parsing the text file (is it streaming in over a connection to an angular front end? Or being read off the server disk?) into a simple class to hold the data, then batting queries off to EF to lookup Rowid based on 123 and marry it with 4..

Comment: ..if you haven't got anything in place for EF yet then I would either gradually repeatedly fill a datatable from a db, or I would pull the entire db down into a datatable that was configured with a PK of 1,2,3 and add 4 from the file to the row. What sort of numbers are you looking at in terms of "how many things are in the db already?" "How many things in the file?" And "what sort of percentage crossover is there between db and file?" E.g for every 100 lines of a file, how many are in the db,what do you do about lines that aren't and is the output expected to contain items that're not in file

Comment: Yes, EF is in the background, might change according to DB, file is "read" by front/program. The data set was already obtained from DB to populate a table on screen, and this field read from the file must be updated on screen, then the data on screen will be (eventually) persisted to db. It is not feasible to query each time to get the RowID, since this library must be stand alone. It must receive the two datasets in which ever structure works best for the merge, matches 3 fields, and returns a merged dataset. The rest of the implementation is Somebody Else's Problem(TM).

Comment: About the other questions, there are less than 100 lines in the text file, all will have a corresponding item in the DB data set. The unmatched DB items must remain in the final data set. If this was a query, it would be an "update DB from TXT".

Comment: It sounds like an ideal candidate for a DataTable Merge; I added an answer. At some point in the future if you want to change this up for a EF based solution, drop a comment here and @ my name so I see it; I'll add another answer for how I currently load a CSV into a DB, using it to add or update new entries. It's about 5 lines of code that does the work plus a couple of classes that represent the in-db data and the in-csv data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest route is to use the functionality built into a datatable for resolving this. It's a single line of code that does the work, but here are 3 steps because of *how the problem is presented in the question*:

1. Set the primary key columns of the table from the db
2. Name the matching columns in the table from the text file as the same
3. Call `dataTableFromDb.Merge(dataTableFromTextFile);`

Step 1:

```
//for example, imagine your DB has given you this:
var dtDb = new DataTable();
dtDb.Columns.Add("RowId");
dtDb.Columns.Add("DF1");
dtDb.Columns.Add("DF2");
dtDb.Columns.Add("DF3");
dtDb.Rows.Add("Rowid1", "A", "B", "C");
dtDb.Rows.Add("Rowid2", "D", "E", "F");

//and your text file has given you this:
var dtF = new DataTable();
dtF.Columns.Add("TF1");
dtF.Columns.Add("TF2");
dtF.Columns.Add("TF3");
dtF.Columns.Add("TF4");
dtF.Rows.Add("A", "B", "C", "4");
```

Step 2: Make sure the column names for the linking columns are the same in each table (rename them earlier in the process to make your life easier, e.g. name them when reading from the text file, or use AS in the SQL when filling dtdb from db)

```
dtF.Columns["TF1"].ColumnName = "DF1";
dtF.Columns["TF2"].ColumnName = "DF2";
dtF.Columns["TF3"].ColumnName = "DF3";
```

Make sure the *destination* table has a primary key

```
dtDb.PrimaryKey = new[] { dtDb.Columns["DF1"], dtDb.Columns["DF2"], dtDb.Columns["DF3"] };
```

Merge the file table into the database table

```
dtDb.Merge(dtF);
```

Realistically, the process that produces the database table should give it its primary key (so step 1 ought to be unnecessary), and the process that generates the table from file should equate the column names (so step 2 ought to be unnecessary) so literally the only line of code you need to use is from Step 3:

```
dtDb.Merge(dtF);
```

The dtDb table is the resulting merged table; you can show it on screen and save it back to the DB etcc

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ia71IM

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you, @Caius-jard,  this is absolutely the easiest way.  Since I'm receiving the datasets as parameters on a function call, this simplifies everything.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly about joining DataTables with composite key using linq, you need to use aliases:

```
var result = from db in dtDB.AsEnumerable()
             join txt in dtTxt.AsEnumerable()
             on new { id = db.Field<string>("ID"), f1 = db.Field<string>("DF1"), f2 = db.Field<string>("DF2") }
                equals new { id = txt.Field<string>("ID"), f1 = txt.Field<string>("TF1"), f2 = txt.Field<string>("TF2") }
             where db.Field<string>("ID") == "xxx"
             select new
             {
                 id = db.Field<string>("ID"),
                 //         F1,
                 //         F2,
                 //         F3,
                 tf4 = txt.Field<string>("TF4")
             };
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll be using this, if this isn't satisfactory to the Powers That Be(TM), i'll let you know.

Comment: Also, @caius-jard is also asking really good questions in the comments. The code smell is using the "awkard" Datatables (older technology), then having to process against them. You may be better off using your own custom objects.

Comment: Ok, DataTables smell rotten, what structure should I use to make it smell "shiny"?

Comment: I see you're talking about 100 lines of text-you are fine. But if you want to scale...reading your other comments: `The data set was already obtained from DB to populate a table on screen`  and you said EF is used (which is not DataTables) - So it looks like your only use of DataTables is for processing text files. DataTables have a lot of overhead. You could import the text files into the database (look up SQLBulkImport) in maybe a temp table, and process/query them using EF or SQL directly. If you need to use a "structure" that you are refering to, you could build your own class/Model/DTO.

Comment: The code I'm writing is for a stand-alone library that has to be imported into both a C# desktop program and a web application. I cannot (should not) access directly neither the db nor the text file, only the referred data sets. I have limited choices to make, and have to follow a lot of "style rules" and "development standards".